# Increase php session time via .htaccess not working

Tags: php, session, .htaccess

I want to create the session timeout to 6 hours but my browser is still timing out in 1/2 hour.

I am on a PLESK server.

I updated .htaccess

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 21600
php_value session.cache_expire 21600
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 21600
```

Here is the relevant PHPinfo:

```
                        Local   Master
session.gc_maxlifetime  21600   1440
session.cache_expire    21600   180
session.gc_maxlifetime  21600   1440
```

Comment: Do these PHP settings apply for all PHP scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Your `php_info()` **proves** that the settings are applied.

Are you on Debian or Ubuntu ? In such case, there's a caveat: debian mantainers have patched the PHP package to clear unused sessions via **crontab**.  (the above could apply not only to Debian/Ubuntu, depends on the distro mantainers)

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find
 /var/lib/php5/ -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -print0 | xargs -n 200 -r -0 rm
```

Such decentralization is thus being done basing on global settings, not on a per process basis.

I see two solutions:

1. after 20 minutes or so (use time() to know when you're above the time threshold) you close the session with `session_write_close()` and open it again.
2. you implement your own session handler with [session_set_save_handler](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) and save your session data somewhere else than the default path.

Whichever route you choose I suggest you to retain the modifications you did to .htaccess.

Let us know how it goes :-)

Comment: The above assumes it is a session time out, not a browser's quirk.

Comment: If you are on Debian a simple solution is to simply add `php_value session.save_path /foo/bar` where /foo/bar is not the standard folder.

Comment: @Zoredache, doing so he may have to delete temporary files manually from /foo/bar since that escapes system crontab's cleaning.

Comment: Thank you for this post, I wasn't aware that my apache config values were being completely ignored, only that my sessions were timing out quickly, until I checked my phpinfo() directly.  As a result, I've given up on using the apache site setup, which apparently may not use php_value at all (unlike a .htaccess?), and just went with editing the php.ini directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it in your code instead.  If you have `header.php` or `config.php` file that is included everywhere add this to it:

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 21600);
session_set_cookie_params(21600);
```